# Component not rendered properly on route change in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component called "Attendance" and it has a report button. I call the following method in attendance.component.ts when the user clicks on "Report" button:

```
gotoAttendanceReport(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/attendance-report'], { queryParams: { subject_id: this.subject_id } });
}
```

Now, in the Attendance Report component, I have the following in ngOnInit:

```
this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.subject_id = params.subject_id;
    });
```

The `subject_id` is then used to fetch the report using an API call. I have used Promise and even call change detection after the data is fetched.

Now, here's the problem: The component view won't render properly on route change. However, when I do a page refresh, it loads just fine. The browser console throws up literally no error, so I have no idea what's going wrong. See the images for reference.

[image: Component on Route Change]

[image: Component after Page Refresh]

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on stackblitz?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have encountered a very similar issue and it would be nice if you could share your solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create elRef variable of type ElementRef in Attendance component.

```
private elRef:ElementRef;
```

and remove Attendance component `onDestroy()`

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.elRef.nativeElement.remove();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try to do communication from one component to another component using @inputs and @outputs

More info 
https://angular.io/api/core/Component

Comment: better statement if it is a comment... ;)